# Correct way to use Vue3 Runtime Compiler

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a functioning Laravel 8 app that has been worked on for the past few months, so it's quite big. Currently I am using jQuery, but I would like to move this over to Vue.

I'm trying to create a simple component, just to check that everything is working properly:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler';
import Welcome from './components/Welcome';
const app = createApp({});
app.component('welcome', Welcome);
app.mount('#app');
```

I realise there are different ways to compile Vue, and I would like it so that I can use single-file Vue components in my Blade views, but keep all of the existing HTML in their that doesn't relate specfically to these components. However when I try this, all of the HTML in the #app div is replaced by this component (which I understand is intended)

This is my mix config file:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix
.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.vue({runtimeOnly: true})
.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
.define({
    __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: true,
    __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false,
});
```

What is the correct way to do this (sorry I'm not good at build tools yet)